# java 8 how to group a collection by list property within that collection

Tags: java, java-8, collectors

So I have a collection of objects Collection and one of the properties on that Book object is List genres.
I want to group my Book objects by genre. I know this is straightforward using java 8 streams, were the property to group by is not a List object. but how can I achieve this 'grouping' by for each element in that list property.

```
String title;
String ISBN,
List<String> genres;

public static void main(String args) {
Book b1 = new Book();
b1.genres = ['Drama', 'Comedy']
Book b2 = new Book();
b2.genres = ['Factual']
Book b3 = new Book();
b3.genres = ['Factual', 'Crime']
Book b4 = new Book();
b4.genres = ['Comedy', 'Action']
//How to now group a collection of book objects by genre so I can get the following grouping:
Drama = [b1], Comedy =  [b1, b4], Factual = [b2, b3], Crime = [b3], Action = [b4] 

}
}
```

Sorry for the poor code example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but how can I achieve this 'grouping' by for each element in that list
>   property.

The key point here is `flatMap` + `map` then group with a `mapping` as a downstream collector.

```
Map<String, List<Book>> result = source.stream()
                .flatMap(book -> book.getGenres().stream().map(genre -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(genre, book)))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getKey,
                        Collectors.mapping(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getValue,
                                Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: perfect thanks! this is actually what i needed! I figured flatMap was what I needed to use here.

Answer (score 2):

And non stream version is just using two nested for loop.

```
Map<String, List<Book>> map = new HashMap<>();
listOfBook.forEach(b -> b.getGenres()
       .forEach(genre ->
           map.merge(genre, new ArrayList<>(Collections.singletonList(b)),
                          (l1, l2) -> { l1.addAll(l2);return l1;})
        )
);
```